# QEMU/KVM: USB3 passthrough to FreeBSD

Tags: usb, freebsd, virtualbox, virtual-machine, qemu

I'm making my first steps in FreeBSD, so please excuse any possible "linuxism".

My goal is to run FreeBSD 10.2 inside virtual machine with QEMU/KVM and allow USB3 network card passthrough from the host to make it the only available WAN interface.

To start QEMU/KVM I run the following:

```
kvm -m 4096 \
-snapshot \
-hda /path/to/the/image \
-device nec-usb-xhci,id=xhci,addr=0x5 \
-device usb-host,bus=xhci.0,vendorid=0x0b95,productid=0x1790 \
-net none
```

This is running fine, if I'm trying to start Ubuntu 16.04. The interface is up, shows up in `lsusb` and the address is assigned by DHCP.
I'm also able to run the very same FreeBSD image with VirtualBox: the card is recognised (as it's supported by FreeBSD) and I see:

```
pciconf -lv
#skipped
xhci0@pci0:0:12:0:  class=0x0c0330 card=0x00000000 chip=0x1e318086 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller'
    class      = serial bus
    subclass   = USB
```

When running QEMU monitor, `info usb` returns (no surprise) the same entry for the network card, both for Ubuntu and FreeBSD.
The only way of adding XHCI controller in QEMU I found is to specify nec-usb-xhci, so far this is the only difference between VirtualBox and QEMU I see.

Is there a way to make this USB3 passthrough to FreeBSD possible with QEMU?

Answer (score 0):

QEMU has a USB3.0 bug which needs to be patched first. 10-stable is known to work with QEMU XHCI now.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2016-08/msg03571.html

--HPS

Comment: Hi @HPS, what do you mean by "10-stable"? Is this a precise qemu version which is patched for USB3?